# Css, after pseudo class

Tags: html, css

So I have a problem placing "|" after a few `<a>` in CSS.
I want it after for all except last one .Thus I tried `.footer-links:after:not(:last-child){
    content: "|";
}` but that did not work.

Any suggestions why and how this can be solved, not using:

`.footer-links:after{
    content: "|";
}`

`.footer-links:last-child:after{
    content: "";
}`

If that is impossible, that is also a solution :)

Thanks!

ps. I'm pretty new to pseudo classes, so ignore my ignorance if there's any :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
.footer-links:not(:last-child):after { content: "|"; }
```